# How redirect in WAMP url ww.xyz.com to ww.abc.com/some-page?

Tags: virtualhost

I am working in site www.example1.com which is hosted in WAMP server, there is another site which is www.example2.com,when a user type www.example2.com in his browser,it should be redirected to www.example1.com/some-page.

VH .conf file for the www

```
<VirtualHost *>
 ServerName www.example2.com
 Redirect 301 / http://example1.com/some-page
</VirtualHost>
```

Currently when a user types example2.com in browser it redirects to something like http://example1.com/some-page/some-page/some-page/some-page/some-page/some-page/some-page/some-page

So, what is the mistake in conf file?

Comment: Are there any redirects in the config for `www.example2.com`?

Comment: Or is the VirtualHost entry for `example1.com` missing? That could  make the `www.example2.com` entry the default VirtualHost and then the redirect points to itself.

Comment: example1.com is default site. So no virtual host entry for this.  
<VirtualHost *>
 ServerName www.example2.com
 Redirect 301 / http://example1.com/some-page
</VirtualHost>
is only entry in config for example2.com